# sqlite3/tkinter: how do I remove treeview row using rowid from database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, treeview

```py
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

app = Tk()
app.geometry('1000x600')

def remove_one():
    x = my_tree.selection()[0]
    my_tree.delete(x)

    conn = sqlite3.connect('CustomerRecords.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    rowid = c.lastrowid

    c.execute("DELETE from customers WHERE rowid = ", (rowid))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

remove_one_button = Button(button_frame, text = 'Remove Record', command= remove_one)
remove_one_button.grid(row =0, column=2, padx = 10, pady = 10)

app.mainloop()
```

output:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input

I want to  be able to delete a row from sqlite3 database using the row id that is naturally assigned to each row

Comment: What do you mean by "incomplete input"?

Comment: Shouldn't the `c.execute("DELETE from customers WHERE rowid = ", (rowid))` actually be `c.execute("DELETE from customers WHERE rowid = ?", (rowid, ))`? I don't know much about SQL so I can't say anything with certainty.

Comment: What do you expect to get from `c.lastrowid` just after connecting a database?

Answer (score 1):

The DELETE SQL statement is obviously incomplete, it should be:

```py
c.execute("DELETE from customers WHERE rowid = ?", (rowid,))
```

How to get the `rowid`?  If you insert those records into `my_tree` like below:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('CustomerRecords.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT rowid, * FROM customers')
for row in c:
    # use `iid` option to store the rowid
    my_tree.insert('', 'end', iid=row[0], values=row[1:])
conn.close()
```

Then you can use `my_tree.selection()[0]` (you already did it in `remove_one()`) to get the rowid of the selected row.

Below is the modified `remove_one()`:

```py
def remove_one():
    selected = my_tree.selection()
    if selected:
        rowid = selected[0]
        my_tree.delete(rowid)

        conn = sqlite3.connect('CustomerRecords.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("DELETE from customers WHERE rowid = ?", (rowid,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    else:
        print("No record selected")
```